# Int32.TryParse() or (int?)command.ExecuteScalar()

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, tryparse, executescalar

I have a SQL query which returns only one field - an ID of type INT.

And I have to use it as integer in C# code.

Which way is faster and uses less memory?

```
int id;
if(Int32.TryParse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out id))
{
  // use id
}
```

or

```
int? id = (int?)command.ExecuteScalar();
if(id.HasValue)
{
  // use id.Value
}
```

or

```
int? id = command.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
if(id.HasValue)
{
  // use id.Value
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but relevant Donald Knuth quote: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Comment: Hey @DannyNeumann, in general, I don't think it makes much sense to post it here since it a question from 2009. In particular, writing efficient code is still important. And this is how I learned to do so. I everyday see horrible, horrible code that would suit Knuth's quote perfectly well. That being said, one should not spend much time on premature optimization of non critical parts, but in the same time one should not write non critical parts inefficiently.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The difference between the three performance wise is negligible. The bottleneck is moving the data from the DB to your app, not a trivial cast or method call.

I would go with:

```
int? id = (int?)command.ExecuteScalar();
if(id.HasValue)
{
  // use id.Value
}
```

It **fails earlier**, if one day people change the command to return a string or a date, at least it will crash and you will have a chance to fix it.

I would also just go with a simple `int` cast **IF** I always expected the command to return a single result.

Note, I usually prefer returning an out param than doing the execute scalar, execute scalar feels fragile (the convention that the first column in the first row is a return value does not sit right for me).

Comment: ExecuteScalar() is a huge win in vb, where you can just do a CInt() or CStr() on it.

Answer (score 19):

If you expect the command to return null, you should keep in mind that database null ([DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx)) is not the same as .NET null. So, conversion of DBNull to int? would fail.

I'd suggest the following:

```
object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
int? id = (int?)(!Convert.IsDBNull(result) ? result : null);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if execute scalar returns no rows, you will get a null. You are correct that if the first row in the first column is null you could be in trouble.

Comment: but then again it's and ID (I at least read that as identity/key) so DBNull is not an issue

Comment: @Sam Saffron, agreed on empty rowset.

@Rune FS, we don't know the underlying logic here. I wouldn't assume whether a query might return null or not, based only on a variable name.

Comment: @VladV agreed you should second guess on variable names but I was referring to the fact that it's an ID being returned (says so in the question) and since ID is short of identity and identity in (MS)DB teminology are unique non null values the question is either ambigious or the query will not return DBNulls :)

Comment: Could you reduce that to `int? id = (int?)command.ExecuteScalar() ?? null;` ?

Answer (score 5):

If none of the above works (especially for users who are battling with MySQL)
why don't you try the following?

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int Result = int.Parse(Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

will work in C#.

Comment: It's a bad approach first dump to string then to parse when object it's already an int, it just requires to be casted.

Answer (score 2):

The latter.  `Convert.ToInt32()` is also an option.

Comment: The first method is from Satan for many reasons.  It's slower AND less readable.  Yuck.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32() worked for me whereas a cast would not, with command.ExecuteScalar();

Answer (score 1):

Use id.HasValue for maximum Nullable Type cool-factor!

Answer (score -2):

```
if ((Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar () ** 1) //en esta parece qu esta el error pero no lo veo
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("error.htm") ;
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Or are you trying to get help? Because that Spanish comment means *'Looks like the error is here but I can't see it'*