# Different mysql Count return value

Tags: c#, mysql, database, count

i have the following query

`SELECT count( * ) COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ptbs.ms_karyawan'`

and execute them on mysql wamp, it returns 2 columns

but then, when i execute the query above using C#, it returns -1 columns, here is the code

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int table = dbc.Count("ptbs.ms_karyawan");
        msg.Sukses("Jumlah table adalah :"+table, "Login");
    }
```

and here is the `dbc.count()` code

```
  public int Count(string table_name)
    {
        string query = "SELECT count( * ) COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = '"+table_name+"'";
        int table = 0;

        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create mysql command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            //Assign the query using CommandText
            cmd.CommandText = query;

            //Assign the connection using Connection
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            //Execute query
            table = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();                             
        }
        return table;
    }
```

why did they return different value, though i'm using the same query ? what did i do wrong ?

Comment: ".. it returns 2 columns",  Columns or Rows?

Comment: @nalaka it returns 2 columns. NIK and Password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to execute `Executescalar` method

```
var retVal = cmd.Executescalar(); 
table = Convert.ToInt32(retVal);
```

`ExecuteNonQuery` return only affected row count.

But `Executescalar` returns first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query

if you need more information about casting value which return from ExcureScalar please check below SO answers

[Int32.TryParse() or (int?)command.ExecuteScalar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174930/int32-tryparse-or-intcommand-executescalar)

Comment: executescalar return error, because cannot implicitly convert object to int

Comment: yes, you need to convert it to int value. executescalar return object value

Answer (score 0):

You're using [MySQLClient.ExecuteNonQuery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-executenonquery) to execute a query  `ExecuteNonQuery` is used for running things like `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements, not `SELECT`.  Because of this you're not affecting any rows, and getting a result of -1.  You need to execute the query in such a way that you get a result set back that you can read the value of your `count ( * ) COLUMN_NAME` from.